# Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

Есть класс:

```
 public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    StartActivity startActivity = new StartActivity();
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Imageview imageview;

    public MainGamePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.one);
        StartActivity.SetTime(5); 
        //StartActivity.imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//в этом случае , как и в случае использования сеттера получаю Null



    }
```

В классе активити:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    ImageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.one);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    }

    public void SetTime (int Seconds1){
       imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

.

```
<view
        class="example.igeniy.MainGamePanel"
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </view>

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</FrameLayout>
```

Если строки

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.one);
imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

перенести в метод `OnCreate`, то всё отображается.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Мне надо из класса MainGamePanel присваивать Imageview различные изображения

Comment: Вот я смотрю на ваш xml и не могу понять, как вы внутри `<view        class="example.igeniy.MainGamePanel"` хотите найти `android:id="@+id/imageView"`? вам надо не `this` в `.findViewById(R.id.imageView)`, а ваше Activity

Comment: Я как только не пробовал. Я объявлял imageview в Activity и через экземпляр класса пытался к нему обратиться, результат тот же.  создавал Сеттер метод и в него писал imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) И всё та же ошибка. Стоит это imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) перенести в метод OnCreate как оно отображается, но держа его в OnCreate я не смогу менять его из другого класса

Comment: Уже есть подозрения , что таким образом вообще нельзя обращаться. Только используя некие Inflatter(ы) но что это и как применить я пока не понял

Comment: А, ну да. Изучайте Inflate :) Без него в андроиде никак, вообще. :)

Comment: смогу ли я эту проблему без него решить или никак ?

Answer (score 1):

В строке:

```
imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

вызывается метод `findViewById(...)` объекта класса `MainGamePanel`, который является субклассом класса `SurfaceView`, который, в свою очередь наследуется от класса `View`.

Так как в классах `MainGamePanel` и `SurfaceView` метод `findViewById(...)` не переопределен, то вызывается реализация этого метода из класса `View`.

Метод `findViewById(...)`, вызванный на некотором объекте `View v` ищет среди дочерних представлений данного `View v` виджет с переданным идентификатором.

Так как у `MainGamePanel` нет дочерних представлений, то метод `findViewById(...)` возвращает `null`.

Далее происходит вызов (не статического) метода `setImageBitmap` на `null`-объекте, отсюда и получается `NullPointerException`.

Как исправить данную проблему глобально и правильно – пересмотреть архитектуру того, что Вы пытаетесь сделать.

Как исправить плохо и локально – можно, например, в `MainGamePanel` передавать ссылку на уже найденный где-то в другом месте (где его можно найти) виджет с идентификатором `R.id.imageView` (например, в том же методе `onCreate(...)`).

Comment: Я так уже делал, пытался локально решить проблему. Объявляю в классе наследуемом от AppCompatActivity Imageview . после нахожу его по идентификатору.  Допустим класс этот называется StartActivity .  В MainGamePanel я пишу через экземпляр класса StartActivity : startActivity.ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) и получаю вновь ту же ошибку.

Comment: Или вот так : Создаю сеттер в StartActivity . в нем пишу ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) и вновь  получаю ошибку. Сам метод сеттер вызывается, если в него Print поставить, то он исполняется. И код верный, если ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) переместить в OnCreate он тоже исполняется, а как через сеттер , то NPE

Comment: @Turalllb, Покажите код, в котором все это присутствует и стек-трейс исключения.

Comment: Ок. Кстати если проверить через экземпляр класса , то  ImageView всё равно Null.

Comment: Вот я правил вопрос с использованием сеттера и со всеми объявлениями

Comment: Вы оказались правы ,что ImageView остается null после того как я его нахожу  методом findViewById(...) в классе наследуемом от View.  Когда я нахожу его в классе наследуемом от AppCompatActivity и проверяю на Null в этом же классе , он действительно не Null. Но когда я через экземпляр класса,который наследует AppCompatActivity провожу проверку на Null , то снова получаю ,что он Null.

Comment: @Turalllb, Когда Вы явно создаете активити с помощью `new StartActivity()`, методы ее жизненного цикла не вызываются, в частности, не вызывается метод `onCreate(...)`, следовательно, инициализации вьюшек не происходит, поэтому и `ImageView` будет `null`.